# Worst-Case For Chordal Completion

Tags: graph-theory

I am interested in the process of [chordal completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_completion) that is the process of creating a chordal graph from a graph $G$ by being the smallest chordal graph that contains $G$ as a sub-graph.

I am in particular trying to find the maximal $k(n)$ such that for a family of graphs with $O(n)$ edges, the chordal completion requires $k(n)$ edges. I am trying to find the maximal $k(n)$, is this exponential in $n$? And is there an explicit construction?

What I have tried is that I think that I have examples where a graph with $n$ edges needs $2n$ edges for the chordal completion.

Comment: As a very trivial bound, $k(n)$ is at most quadratic in $n$ since the complete graph is chordal. So you're definitely not going to end up with an exponential $k(n)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I completely missed that.